# ASP.NET Post request does not send value

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to send the value via JS code value via Post request, but I don't get this value. I can't figure out what the problem is.

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#TestButton").click(function (e) {
        var valueToSend = 1; 
        $.ajax({
            url: "Home/TestMethod",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: valueToSend,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (response) {
                alert("Success");
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert("Failed");
            },
        })
    })
})
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult TestMethod(int testNumber)
    {
        var value = testNumber;
        return View(nameof(Index));
    }
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Test" class="btn btn-default" id="TestButton" />
</div>
```

I expect to get the number 1, but the number 0 comes.
[The result of the post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loA4N.png)

Comment: How is `valueToSend` formatted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The `TestMethod(int testNumber)` action method is expecting parameter `int testNumber`, therefore it's necessary to use this name when referencing to the parameter in the JavaScript.
2. Remove the [`contentType`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) definition. By default it will be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` which is fine for most cases.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#TestButton").click(function (e) {
        var valueToSend = 1; 
        $.ajax({
            url: "Home/TestMethod",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { testNumber: valueToSend },
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (response) {
                alert("Success");
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert("Failed");
            },
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are sending 1 in the request body. However, it doesn't seem like your endpoint expects a request body. It probably treats the `testNumber` argument as a query string parameter. Try calling your endpoint with query string parameter.

`Home/TestMethod?testNumber=1`

Another option is that you can try adding `[FromBody]` attribute to the `testNumber` argument.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult TestMethod([FromBody] int testNumber)
{
    var value = testNumber;
    return View(nameof(Index));
}
```